# Why iframe to not exist file create empty file?

Tags: javascript, python, django, iframe

I need some help or advise. In the template of django application I have iframe widget where user select date and load xls file by url address which I set in js. If file with selected date is not exist I want to show message about it. For some reason in that case iframe create empty xls file. How to fix it?

**JS:**

```
var downloadSideBarFiles = {
    main_url: "https://example.com",
    file_types: {
        2: "/shares/rpfile/",
        1: "/shares/waprfile/"
    },
    init: function() {
        var e = $(".regulations__download");
        this.clickMethod(this, e)
    },
    clickMethod: function(e, a) {
        a.find(".regulation__download-link").click(function(t) {
            t.preventDefault();
            var r = a.find("input[type=radio]:checked"),
                o = a.find("input[type=text]");
            0 == r.length ? e.errorMethod("No file type selected") : 0 == o.val().length ? e.errorMethod("No date selected") : (type = e.file_types[r.val()], date = o.val().split("/").join("."), uri = e.main_url + type + date, e.downLoadMethod(e, uri))
        })
    },
    errorMethod: function(e) {
        alert(e)
    },
    downLoadMethod: function(e, a) {
        $.fileDownload(a).fail(function() {
            e.errorMethod("File is not exist")
        })
    }
};
```

**views.py:**

```
def warpfile_date(request, date):
    if urllib.urlopen(filepath+ 'wapr' + str(date) + '.xls').code == 200:
        file = urllib.urlopen(filepath)
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + 'wapr' + '.xls'
    else:
        response = HttpResponse(status=404)
    return response
```

Comment: Where is `filepath` coming from in that view? And why are you using `urllib` to open a file path?

Comment: Hello! :) `filepath` here is constant, I just don't wrote it here. I set in the same view. What's wrong with `urllib`?